# Difference between capacity and max_htlc in Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, hash-time-locked-contract, transaction-capacity

What is the difference between *capacity* and *max_htlc* in the routing of payments in the network?

Answer (score 1):

The `capacity` of a channel is the number of satoshis that are stored in the payment channel. They are split between the two channel partners and offered `htlcs`. No payment larger than the capacity can ever go through that channel.

The `max_htlc` is the number of concurrent offered `htlcs` that are possible in the channel. They are limited because most `htlcs` are outputs in the commitment transaction and cost a fee paid to the miners in case the channel has to be force closed.